# Bootstrap with Search Bar Not Scaling to Mobile

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have written code for a Delivery page using Bootstrap CSS with only a few custom CSS classes (they all have to do with coloring and such, no positioning). I am wondering why it looks so nice on desktop but does not scale well to mobile, I have not had this sort of a problem before using Bootstrap.

Any idea where I went wrong here? I have copied the HTML below.

```
<div class="container content">
    <div class="row">
        <h2><u>Delivery</u></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form">
                <md-input-container>
                    <label>Address/Restaurant</label>
                    <input g-places-autocomplete options="autocompleteOptions" ng-model="vm.place"/>
                </md-input-container>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <h3>OR</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <md-button class="md-raised currentloc-btn" ng-click="vm.useCurrentLocation()">
                <div class="green-btn">
                    Use Current Location
                </div>
            </md-button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-click="vm.selectOrder()" ng-repeat="order in vm.orders">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">{{order.restaurant}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">Bounty: {{order.bounty}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">{{order.address}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">{{order.distance}} miles</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">{{order.shortOrder}}</div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">Needs by: {{order.deliverTime}}</div>
        </div>
        <hr ng-if="vm.orders.length > 1">
    </div>
</div>
```

*Note:* It is in Angular so I have simply copied the body UI view code, as the header and footer should not be relevant.

Custom CSS is below per request.

```
.content {
    width: 1000px;
    padding: 80px;
}

.deliver-input {
    background-color: #f2f2f2; 
}

.currentloc-btn {
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}

.green-btn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

Desktop view: 
[image]

Mobile view:
[image]

Comment: Need to see the styles for your green-btn, it looks like it has a fixed width

Comment: Will edit post with my custom CSS as well. Done.

Comment: Why would you give `.container` a fixed width of `1000px`?  Also, you're setting a `position` of `absolute` on `.currentloc-btn`

Comment: removing those rules causes it to work significantly better: http://www.bootply.com/WcXRHxuXTp

Comment: Thanks @JosephMarikle, that was very helpful. Not sure what I was thinking, I hacked at it a bit to make it look nice and ended up messing some things up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every row needs 12 columns defined.

For example, this:

```
<div class="row">
    <h2><u>Delivery</u></h2>
</div>
```

Should be this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <h2><u>Delivery</u></h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

And set the css for your buttons to display:block and width:100% for mobile using a media query if you want the buttons to fit the column width.

Finally, do not set a fixed width on the container. It is best to leave the container alone unless you are using the Sass or LESS version as there are a bunch of css classes for the grid that depend on a flexible width. If you want to set your content wider than the Bootstrap grid, use the Sass/Less version and adjust the column width and/or gutters then recompile it.